# how to overload + and += operators as non-member functions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently trying to refresh and improve my C++ skills and I'm reading a few books in parallel depending on the subject I need to dig into.

I'm currently spending time on The C++ Programming Language from Stroustrup. At page 61/62, there's an example of class for Complex numbers. It overloads a number of operators like += and -=. At the same time, it says that "Many useful operations do not require direct access to the representation of complex, so they can be defined separately from the class definition".

Now, when I try the following code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
private:
    double re, im;
public:
    Complex(double r, double i): re{r}, im{i} {}
    Complex(double r): re{r}, im{0} {}
    Complex(): re{0}, im{0} {}

    double real() const { return re; }
    void real(double d) { re = d; };
    double imag() const { return im; }
    void imag(double d) { im = d; }
    void print();

    Complex& operator+= (Complex z) { re += z.re, im += z.im; return *this; }
    Complex& operator-= (Complex z) { re -= z.re, im -= z.im; return *this; }
};

Complex operator+ (Complex a, Complex b) { return a += b; }
```

I get a link error: `class Complex_cdecl operator+(class Complex, class Complex)` already defined in `Complex.obj`
One or more multiply defined symbols found.

So, I suppose the code presented in the book here is only partial. I can't figure out though what's the right way to `overload` both `+` and `+=`. Is the book wrong here or obsolete?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the `operator +` should either be made `inline` so that the linker knows that multiple obj files can contain the same function definition.

```
inline Complex operator+ (Complex a, Complex b) { return a += b; }
```

Or the header file should contain only the declaration

```
Complex operator+ (Complex a, Complex b);
```

and exactly one cpp file should contain the definition

```
Complex operator+ (Complex a, Complex b) { return a += b; }
```

Comment: I would recommend such a signature
`Complex operator+ (const Complex& a, const Complex& b);`

Comment: @AntonShwarts, [why](https://godbolt.org/z/7p4HWw)?

Comment: @AntonShwarts That might be an enhancement. [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in) has some guidance on when to pass by value or by const reference.

Comment: The guidance in CppCoreGuidelines for this particular case is to pass by value. On my platform, the break-even point is objects that are 512 bytes or smaller should be passed by value rather than pass by reference to const. But that can only be determined empirically by profiling with an optimized build.